# Identifying records present in one dataframe column but not present in another dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to select all elements present in foo but not present in bar. I'm using this code:

```
foo.repartition(1)
foo.cache()
bar.repartition(1)
bar.cache()
foo.select("col_1").except(bar.select("col_1"))
```

Is there a better or faster way to do this? This is currently taking more than 15+ mins when running on a cluster.

Additional info:
foo will have around 100-1000 elements. bar will have 40 million+ elements. foo is a dataframe consisting of data read from hive table(50 columns) using Spark SQL. bar is a dataframe consisting of data read from kudu table(250 columns) using KuduContext.

Using Spark 2.2 on CDH 5.15.x with Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: Curious: why are you using `repartition(1)`? Especially for `bar` (the larger dataframe). Did you try omitting the repartition? You're forcing Spark to use a single executor for this job which might slow things down significantly

Comment: I tried without the `repartition(1)` for both dataframes. I added it after I read a few other posts, thinking it might help. I'm relatively new to using Spark. Also, there was no time difference with or without `repartition(1)`.

Comment: FWIW, for `bar`, the dataframe from kudu table, the table itself has `hash partition` defined on primary key(columns). `col_1` is one of the primary key columns.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tzach suggested it is better to avoid using `bar.repartition(1)` and `bar.cache()` since the bar dataset seems to be too big to fit in memory. You can use cache for the small dataset though or even better to try to broadcast it to each executor. Also if you know the size of the big dataset you can calculate the partition number with `partition_num = total_size / 500MB`, 250-500 MB is the ideal size of each partition therefore if your data is 10GB this should be 10GB/500MB = 20 partitions.

Here is your code after the mentioned changes:

```
foo.cache() //feel free to cache the small dataset
bar.repartition(partitions_num) //this is optional

foo.select("col_1").except(bar.select("col_1"))
```

Also you can try to use an [left_anti](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/little-known-spark-dataframe-join-types-cc524ea39fd5) join instead as shown next and compare their performance:

```
foo.join(bar, foo("col_1") === bar("col_1"), "left_anti").show
```

This will exclude all records from foo for which *col_1* exists in bar.

If your requirements required the opposite aka excluding records from bar that exist in foo then your program could be even more efficient by broadcasting the small dataset foo as in the next code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

bar.join(broadcast(foo), bar("col1") === foo("col1"), "left_anti").show
```

Good luck!